# populating JavaScript key value pair

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, key-value

I have a form with file-names and check-boxes that comes from the server already pre-populated.  My form is supposed to update the check boxes.

I have code in JavaScript  that selects the rows and attempts to build a key value object with the updated values from the check-boxes in each row.

When the selector is set to only return the ones that are checked, the dictionary gets built perfectly, but I also want to add to the dictionary the entries that might have gotten ticked off.

When I make the selector select all rows (including where the checked attribute is undefined) then the dictionary doesn't get populated at all.

Here is my input element:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Map" data-id="@file.FileId" checked="checked" class="auto-accept-checkbox" />
```

Here is the javascript snippet:

```
var map = {};

$("#shareable-file-settings-form table tr").each(function () {
    map[$(this).attr('data-id')] = $(this).attr('checked') === 'checked';
});
```

I have tried on the console item by item and my right hand operand expression works there! I don't know why that look would misbehave like that (not putting anything in the dictionary) when the selector is modified

from:

```
"#shareable-file-settings-form table tr :checked"
```

to:

```
"#shareable-file-settings-form table tr"
```

Comment: It's not working because you're selecting `tr` elements which can't have a `checked` property and which probably don't have `data-id` set. Your first selector is working because it's selecting checked checkboxes that are children of your `tr`s. Try `#shareable-file-settings-form table tr input[type="checkbox"]` as the selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Joe said, you're selecting the `tr` element, not the `input[type=checkbox]` inside.  First, change your selector to

```
"#shareable-file-settings-form table tr input[type=checkbox]"
```

Further, the "checked" property on checkboxes is an HTML property, not an attribute.  Also, you can use jQuery's `.data()` method to access the `id` data attribute.

You can change it to

```
map[$(this).data('id')] = $(this).prop('checked');
```